# How to prove that Kantorovich's metric is actually a metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$d(\mu_1, \mu_2) = \inf\limits_{L}\big\{\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}|x - y| \mathrm{d}L(x,y)\big\}$, where $L$ - measure on square $[0,1]^2$ such that $L([0,1] \times A) = \mu_2(A)$, $L(A \times [0,1]) = \mu_1(A)$. (Kantorovich's metric)

I need help with proof that all of them axioms is right for $d(\mu_1, \mu_2)$:

1. $d(\mu_1, \mu_2) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \mu_1 = \mu_2$,
2. $d(\mu_1, \mu_2) = d(\mu_2, \mu_1)$
3. Triangle inequality

I proofed (1) but it works only this way:

$d(\mu_1, \mu_2) = 0 \Rightarrow \mu_1 = \mu_2$

I've used Random variables from Probability theory in this way

$\mu_1(A)$ is a distribution of a variable $\xi$ and $\mu_2(A)$ is a distribution of a variable $\eta$, where $\xi$ and $\eta$ are Random variables

So using expected value of $|\xi-\eta|$ I proofed this implication:
$d(\mu_1, \mu_2) = 0 \Rightarrow \mu_1 = \mu_2$

But I need help with other paragraphes. I hope you'll help me

Comment: You could look this up in ```C. Villani - Topics in Optimal transportation```, theorem 7.3 or theorem 8.3 in ```Luigi Ambrosio et. al - Lectures on optimal transport``` or theorem 3.1.5 in ```Figalli, Glaudo - An invitation to optimal transport, Wasserstein distances and gradient flows```.

Comment: For $\mu_1 = \mu_2 \implies d(\mu_1, \mu_2)=0$, consider the joint distribution $L$ where $\xi = \eta$ almost surely.